# Minimize the DFA(Deterministic finite Automata) given in the picture

Tags: finite-automata

[image: DFA]How to minimize the DFA given in the picture

Comment: What's stopping you from using any of the standard DFA minimization techniques?

Comment: Confused about the elimination of 't'...getting multiple answers.

Answer (score 0):

Add p and q and make them as a single state.
Combine s and u because they Are final states.
We cannot combine t and r because on the same input they go to different states.
you will understand good when u see the minimized DFA given below
Now we obtain 4terms {(p,q),r,t,(s,u)}[image: you can check the minimized DFA in this]

Comment: What about the unlabelled arrow into $p$ in the question's image?

Answer (score 0):

Here we can combine p and q to form a single state because p on 0 as input goes to state q and q on 0 as input goes to state p and both p and q go to state s on 1 as input.Similarly we can combine states s and u because state s goes to u on both inputs 0 and 1 and state u stays in the same state on inputs 0 and 1.We can't combine r and t as they don't reach same state on same inputs.The minimised DFA is having 4 states as follows: [image]